# change in one item re runs whole map component loop in ReacJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am dispatching an add comment action on a specific post re runs component loop again instead of updating a specific one. Suppose, If I have 100 posts adding comments to one post runs the component loop again and iterates again 100 times. Is there is any way to re-render only a specific item instead of running the whole component loop again?

Here's my code of the looped component

```
const Post = ({totalComments, like, _id, image, caption}) => {
    const {enqueueSnackbar} = useSnackbar();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.loadUser);
    const { loading: loadingComments, comments } = useSelector((state) => state.listComments);
    const { success: addCommentSucess, error: addCommentError } = useSelector((state) => state.addComment);
    const [openComment, setOpenComment] = useState('');
    const [commentsLength, setCommentsLength] = useState(totalComments);

  //listing of comments
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (addCommentError) {
      enqueueSnackbar(addCommentError, {variant: 'error'});
      dispatch(clearErrors());
    }


  }, [addCommentError, addCommentSucess, dispatch, enqueueSnackbar]);

  const openCommentHandler = () => {
      dispatch(listComments(_id));
    setOpenComment(!openComment);
  }

  const addCommentHandler = (data) => {
      console.log('addcomehandle')
    dispatch(addComment(data));
    setCommentsLength(commentsLength+1);
  }
 

  return (
    <Card className='post-container'>

        <div className='button-wrapper'>
          <IconButton onClick={openCommentHandler} color={openComment ? 'primary' : 'default'}>
            <SvgIcon component={CommentOutlinedIcon} />
          </IconButton>
          <p>{commentsLength}</p>
        </div>

      {!loadingComments && openComment && (
        <Comments comments={comments} />
      )}

      <Divider />
      <AddComment onAddComment={addCommentHandler} postId={_id} />
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: You can make a pure `Comment` component and pass the id of the comment to that component, that component selects the comment from state (only works if you don't refresh all data from json). An example can be found [here](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors/blob/master/src/components/Person/index.js) You cannot prevent the map from running again but can prevent each comment item from re creating jsx.

Comment: Sorry @HMR , Actually I'm new to react and this my first personal big project. I'm not getting the example you gave me. Can you please do me a favor and make piece of code for me?

Comment: The link in the previous comment contains a working project that has a list rendering each item as pure component (using React.memo) and a readme that explains how to use selectors with reselect.